# Invalid hooks call while using createRoot in react18

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-18

`enter code here`I was building my project and came across this error in which the console is showing
invalid hooks call..... i have gone through all react documents and tried everything.

this is the code for the index.js

```
import React from "react"
// import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from "../src/App"
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />)

//This is the code for the App component

import React from "react";
import {Container,AppBar,Typography,Grow,Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import Posts from "./Component/Posts/Posts";
import Form from "./Component/Form/Form";

const App =  () => {
    return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <AppBar position="static" color = 'inherit'>
                <Typography variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography> 
                {/* { <img src={memories} alt = "memories" height="60" /> } */}

            </AppBar>
            <Grow in>
                <Container>
                    <Grid container justify-content = "space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs ={12} sm={7}>
                        <Posts />
                            
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs ={12} sm={4}>

                        <Form />
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Grow>
        </Container>
    )

}
export default App
```

After this when I ran the App it was completely blank so I open the console and it showed the message for invalid hooks call
As a viewer had said to add error i am also adding the Screen shot of the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNhS3.png)

Comment: Please add your error here too...

Comment: The error should give you a stack trace, where did the error originate? (I can't see anything in the index that would cause it)

Comment: I think this error occurred in other component - not App.js and index.js